# inverse number using function - how to solve this output problem?

Tags: c

As a new learner of C, I managed to go this far in this little exercice, the code works (kind of). It doesn't work for the second time, the output just adds up.

```
int i = 0;

void inverse(unsigned int n) {
    int reste;
    if (n != 0) {
        reste = n % 10;
        i = (i * 10) + reste;
        inverse(n / 10);
    } else {
        printf("%d \n", i);
    }
}

void main() {
    inverse(1589);
    inverse(42);    
}
```

Output:

```
9851
985124
```

Comment: You need to reset `i` at some point. The most straight forward and horrible way is to simply do it after the `printf()`. But you should better redesign the recursion to work without global variables. Which is not easily done with any similarity to the shown code....

Answer (score 1):

Your approach fails because `i` is not cleared before each new case. You could clear `i` after the `printf`, but a better approach is to avoid global variables. You can modify `inverse` for this purpose by removing the recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inverse(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        unsigned int reste = n % 10;
        i = i * 10 + reste;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    printf("%u\n", i);
}

int main() {
    inverse(1589);
    inverse(42);
    return 0;    
}
```

Note these remarks:

- you must include `<stdio.h>` to use `printf()`
- `main` return type is `int`.
- for consistency, `i` should have type `unsigned int`.

Some numbers will produce incorrect output as their *inverse* exceeds the range of `unsigned int` eg: `1000000009`. You can remove this shortcoming by printing the digits instead of combining them as a number:

```
void inverse(unsigned int n) {
    while (n > 9) {
        putchar('0' + n % 10); 
        n = n / 10;
    }
    putchar('0' + n); 
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `i` at some point. The most straight forward and horrible way is to simply do it after the printf().

But you should better redesign the recursion to work without global variables. Which is not easily done with any similarity to the shown code.
This is (I realised a little late) more or less what luk2302 recommended in a comment on a deleted answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0;
void inverse(unsigned int n){
    
    int reste;
    if (n != 0) {
        reste = n % 10;
        i = (i * 10) + reste;
        inverse(n / 10);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d \n", i);
        i=0;
    }
}

void inverse2(int number, int reversed)
{
    if (number < 1)
    {
        printf("%d \n",reversed);
    } else
    {
        inverse2(number/10, reversed*10+number%10);
    }
    
}

void main(){

    inverse(1589);
    inverse(42);    
    inverse(123);    
    inverse2(1589,0);
    inverse2(42,0);    
    inverse2(123,0);    

}
```

Output:

```
9851 
24 
321 
9851 
24 
321
```